# Generate hierarchical structure based on relational data

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, tree

Given list of employee and their subordinates. How do I create an efficient recursive function to get tree structure with manager and subordinates relations and return top manager. All the names are unique so they can be considered as employeeId.

```
[
    {
      name: 'Chris',
      subordinates: ["Jim Beglin","Rosey","Chuloo"]
    },
    {
      name: 'Jim Beglin',
      subordinates: ["Mike", "Liz"]
    },
    {name: 'Mike'},
    {name: 'Liz'},
    {
      name: 'Rosey',
      subordinates: ["Annie","Michelle", "Sam", "Ivy"]
    },
    {name: 'Annie'},
    {name: 'Michelle'},
    {name: 'Sam'},
    {name: 'Ivy'},
    {
      name: 'Chuloo',
      subordinates: [ "Nick","Charly","Steph","Jon"]
    },
    {name: 'Nick'},
    {
      name: 'Charly'
      subordinates: ["Law"]
    },
    {name: 'Law'},
    {name: 'Steph'},
    {name: 'Jon'}
  ]
```

Comment: Please edit tags and add the programming language you're going to use

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of employee, where each node of employee denotes the sub-employee they have. you can proceed to call a function recursively with List and array of objects. you can follow the algorithm.

**algorithm [pseducode]:**

```
function makeEmployeeTree(List list, Array objects){
      if(objects length == 0) return;

      if(list isEmpty()){
          list.add(objects[0]);
          remove -> objects[0] from objects;
      }
      else{
          traverse -> list:
                 if (currentnode contains subordinates  == objects[0]){
                           insert -> objects[i] in currentnode;
                           remove -> objects[0] from objects;
                  }
           // in-case no subordinates found, append in list
           insert -> objects[0] at the of list;
           remove -> objects[0] from objects;
      }
      // recursively call the funtion for following object from objects;
      makeEmployeeTree(list, objects);
}
```

> Now after making list in hierarchical order, print each node in dfs order to get the desired output.. that's it. *happy coding*

Comment: reply here, if you couldn't understand the pseudocode over there, I will add the code later.